# How to convert week number and year into unix timestamp?

Tags: php, strtotime, strftime, mktime

I'm trying to group together dates into a week number and year, and then I want to convert that week number back into a unix timestamp. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "convert a week number into a timestamp"

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I assume you are using ISO 8601 week numbers, and want the first day of a ISO 8601 week so that e.g. `Week 1 of 2011` returns `January 3 2011`.

`strtotime` can do this out of the box using the `{YYYY}W{WW}` format:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2011W01")); // 2011-01-03
```

Note that the week number needs to be *two* digits.

Shamefully, `DateTime::createFromFormat`, the fancy new PHP 5 way of dealing with dates, seems unable to parse this kind of information - it doesn't have a "week" placeholder.

Comment: While the note about `DateTime::createFromFormat()` is still true today unfortunately, I want to add that you can still use DateTime for that: `new DateTime('2011W01')` does work.

Comment: While this works... do you know where the official documentation is for this? strtotime (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) points you at DateFormats (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) which doesn't mention this format. Although I see Date (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) does.

Comment: Documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php Localized notations:  ISO year with ISO week YY "-"? "W" W "2008W27", "2008-W28"

Answer (score 2):

- `$week`: The week number
- `$year`: The year number

Then:

```
$timestamp = gmmktime (0, 0 , 0 , 1, , 4 + 7*($week - 1), $year);
```

The `4 + 7*($week - 1)` comes from the fact that [according to ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), the first week of the year is the one that contains January 4th.

Comment: I don't think this is reliable: `1/1/2011` was still in week 52/2010 according to ISO 8601.

Comment: @Pekka This only matters if the conversion should be reversible in a trivial manner. Changed it nevertheless.

Comment: This returns January 4, 2008 for week 1 of 2008, but that week starts December 31, 2007 according to ISO.

Comment: I'd not recommend this solution. There are few places where I'd suggest using `mktime()` or `gmmktime()` in place of `strtotime()`

Comment: @Pekka A week is a time span, so it can, by definition, not be converted into a timestamp (i.e. a single point in time). The only thing that can be done is take a timestamp that represents that week. This representative does not need to be the beginning of the week (unless otherwise stated in the requirements).

Comment: @Oswald well, fair point. The OP indeed needs to clarify what they want.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime('1/1/2011 + 4 weeks')` (1/1 ist always in week number one; this would bring me to week number five). if you want *any* timestamp in the week then that's all you need, else you would have to go to the monday in this week:

```
$t = strtotime('1/1/2011 + 4 weeks');
$t -=  24 * 60 * 60 * date('w', $t);
```

**Update**: Instead of `1/1/2011` use the first monday in 2011. The 2nd calculation is not needed anymore.

Comment: I don't think this is reliable: `1/1/2011` was still in week 52/2010 according to ISO 8601.

Comment: Week 1 of 2008 was December 31, 2007. This won't work in this scenario