# Year, number of week and day of week to date in php

Tags: php, date

I have three pieces of information extracted from my database, the year, the number of week (1-52), and the day of week (mon, tue, wed). And I need to convert it in to a date.

How would I go about doing that in php?

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Very close to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763340/how-to-convert-week-number-and-year-into-unix-timestamp PHP `strtotime()` will do it for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$yr="2014";
$week="01";
$day = "Mon";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yr."W".$week."D ".$day));
```

PHP fiddle:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nzg-ws6

Comment: I tried this: $yr="2014";
$week="01";
$day ='mon';

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yr."W".$week."D ". $day));

and it resulted:

2014-01-03 

It's wrong. Because, 2014-01-3 it's Friday!

Answer (score 1):

Did a little digging and it looks like the day will need to be in numerical format for the strtotime conversion to work properly. Using a string such as 'Monday' won't work.

```
$yr = "2014";
$week = "01";
$day = "1"; //Monday
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yr . "W" . $week . $day)); // "2014W011"
```

Note that I didn't include the 'D' prefix for the day as this looks to be following [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates).

Swapping your days to numbers can be done a few ways:
You could make an array Monday to Sunday and use the array key, or maybe a little easier you could do something like this:

```
$day date("N", strtotime("Monday")); // will echo 1
```

So the full code could look something like this:

```
$yr = "2014";
$week = "01";
$day = date("N", strtotime("Monday")); //
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yr . "W" . $week . $day)); // "2014W011"
```

Here is a demo to check: http://3v4l.org/EllgQ

Answer (score 0):

This converts you $day value to desired day format.
try this

```
$yr="2011";
$week="01";
$day="Monday";
$day=date("D",strtotime($day));
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yr."W".$week."D ".$day));;
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/tObeQ)

Comment: I tried this: <?php
$yr="2014";
$week="01";
$day="mon";
$day=date("D",strtotime($day));
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yr."W".$week."D ".$day));;
    
?>

and the results it's the same :x it's wrong

Comment: i too checked after your reference.it is wrong.Will update if found soln.