# strftime with week number format {YYYY}W{WW} gives wrong week

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a {YYYY}W{WW} string with strftime as explained is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5763408/1154380).

However it always gives W-1 :

```
echo $date = utf8_encode(strftime('%B %Y, week %W', strtotime('2015W38')));
// this will echo "September 2015, week 37"
// but should echo "September 2015, week 38"
```

How can I properly correct this ?

PHP Version : 5.6.9

Comment: Please make sure you specify a clear **input** and **output**, your question isn't clear on that.

Comment: If I understand what you say correctly, output is on 2nd line of code.

Comment: **// gives September 2015, week 37** is this the expected output ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php):

> ISO year with ISO week    YY "-"? "W" W   "2008W27", "2008-W28"

[strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

> %W    A numeric representation of the week of the year, starting with the
>   first Monday as the first week    46 (for the 46th week of the year
>   beginning with a Monday)
>
> %V    ISO-8601:1988 week number of the given year, starting with the
>   first week of the year with at least 4 weekdays, with Monday being the
>   start of the week 01 through 53 (where 53 accounts for an overlapping
>   week)

So probably you should use

```
echo $date = utf8_encode(strftime('%B %Y, week %V', strtotime('2015W38')));
```

Desclaimer: I am not proficient with php, so please do validate my thoughts.

EDIT>

As @syck adds: ISO 8601 counts weeks from 01 and the first week is the one with the year's first Thursday in it (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)).

Comment: For completeness: _The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the year's first Thursday in it._

Answer (score 2):

This works as intended:

```
$year = "2015"; // Year 2015
$week = "38"; // Week 38
$date1 = date( "F Y, W", strtotime($year."W".$week) );
echo $date1;
//September 2015, 38
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace %W with %V