# How do I find date ranges given a certain week number and year?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

Is there a way to calculate start and end date in YYYY-MM-DD format given a year and a week number?

For example, week 3 of 2019 goes from 2019-01-14 to 2019-01-20.

I've thought about using `mktime` and then adding +7 days, but it has no week parameter.

I'm using PHP 5.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert week number and year into unix timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763340/how-to-convert-week-number-and-year-into-unix-timestamp)

Comment: Yes, this works fine: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2019W03 +7 days"))`. Thanks!